# Is it possible to make multiple intersecting geometries into a single geometry in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to dissolve multiple intersecting geometries into one single geometry. Is it possible to do that in PostGIS ?
[image: I want to achieve second figure from first]

Comment: I thought polygons have straight side elements with point vertices

Comment: Updated polygon to geometry.

Comment: I was thinking about a generic algorithm to do that conversion. It's really hard if we're talking polygons. It much harder to use the curved segments you are talking, especially when you have created concave segments.

Comment: Have you seen [PostGIS Vector Tile Utils at github](https://github.com/mapbox/postgis-vt-util). Pretty impressive.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks pretty good.

Comment: Easy, use ST_Union

Comment: ST_Union does the job. But it is very slow when the intersecting buffers increases to 30000. Is there any other alternative ?